# Facebook logout in Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using the old facebook sdk, fbconnect, and I am forcing the app to login to facebook using webui via `Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH` to launch the webview even if I have the facebook app, so my question is, I try logging out the user by calling

```
facebook.setAccessToken(""); 
facebook.setAccessExpires(100);
```

but the thing is my user is still not logged out, so I delete the database like this

```
deleteDatabase("webview.db");
deleteDatabase("webview.db-journal");
deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

but still not logged out, need help please

Answer (score 0):

You change your code as follow so that it will logout facebook programmatically.

```
facebook.setAccessToken(null); 
facebook.setAccessExpires(0);
```

It worked for me and I hope it works for you also.

Comment: okay will try that will post the results here immediately tnx

Comment: btw i am using FORCE_AUTH_DIAG so even if i have facebook app it launches webview

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
facebook.logout(yourMainActivity);
```

Comment: i used this like this, LoginActivity.facebook.logout(Context of LogoutActivity); surrounded by try catch